Dynamics 365 Sales: Custom Business Process Flow not displaying on Opportunity, but works fine on Lead
I have created a custom Business Process Flow (BPF). This works fine when I add a new Lead I see the new custom BPF at the top. Then Qualify this to become an Opportunity, and I also see the new custom BPF at the top.
If I create a New Opportunity though, the default BPF is shown not the custom one. Also some of my existing opportunities show the custom BPF and some show the default one.
I've tried turning the default one off, and removing it from the Solution. I've removed permissions for all users to see the default one too. But as administrator I can't seem to get rid of the default one which keeps appearing. I can't see on the New Opp. Form that there is any way of specifying which BPF to use.
So confused! How do I force New Opportunity to use the Custom BPF? (see image showing, new Opp and new Lead screens)



You have to change the order of Business Process Flows (see quote below)
You already disabled default BPF for other security roles as needed, but keep in mind, you can't modify permissions for System Administrator security role. You need to test these changes under a user account to make sure it works as expected
After you change the order, new records should get your custom flow. Try changing the process manually using Process > Switch Process toolbar button for records still displaying default flow


You can associate business process flows with security roles so that
only people with those security roles can see or use them. You can
also set the order of the business process flows so that you can
control which business process flow will be set by default. To set
business process flow order, open a business process flow in the
designer and then select Order Process Flow on the command bar. Select
the up and down arrows to move the business process flows in the order
you want. Source

